# Android WebView Override Post Request

Tags: android, iframe, webview, get, request

I have an app with a WebView (you should know that the website is not mine). At some point there is a post request and after it the WebView loads a page with pdf in `<iframe>`. Sadly Android doesn't support this. I want to replace the src url in the iframe with a google docs url. The problem is that I MUST make the request only once. I already have a method that sends a GET request to get the html code and then I parse it but this is done in `onPageStarted()` and it doesn't work for me. How can I call my method to make the request instead of the webview or can you give any other suggestion to replace the pdf url? It will be really helpful if you give an example (I'm new at mobile web apps). 
Thanks!